# Usb 3.0 Is in a Failed State. Usb 3.0 Super Speed doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-3

Three weeks ago my USB 3.0 ports stopped working on 3 different computers, all within 20 minutes of each other. All three computers are different ages, makes, and models. The 3.0 ports had worked for years with no issues prior to this.

The ONLY thing that changed on all 3 was Windows critical updates that Windows 10 forced my computer to install. Despite this Windows customer support INSISTS that the problem is due to 3 different motherboards failing all at the same time, and needing updates from their manufacturers. I find this *stupidly* implausible.

I have done a stupid amount of work to try and fix this: Uninstalling USB drivers, updating BIOS/UFEI, updating chipsets, rolling back Windows, even reinstalling Windows 10 completely (I only have access to the latest version, with the updates included). NOTHING has worked. My USB controller is in a failed state and my 3.0 ports only operate at 2.0.

USBTreeView shows me that I *do* have superspeed ports, but that nothing ever connects to them. Also I can use USBTreeView to restart the USB 2.0 and High-speed ports, but I get an error when I try to restart the 3.0 ports.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can download older Windows 10 installation media from Microsoft, just google "windows 10 download".

Comment: On a computer where you have not re-installed Windows or rolled it back, try in Device Management to rollback the USB3 driver (under "Universal Serial Bus controllers" usually called "USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller"). If this works, take a backup of it. Questions: To which USB3 controller are your ports connected? Have you tried front and back ports on the computers? (May the Force be with you.)

Comment: Unfortunately there's no roll back option - it's completely grayed out

Comment: You can uninstall that windows update, see if that fixes your issue, but windows will soon install it again, but at least you will know what caused it.